# PHP is adding the drive name to the start of all URLs

Tags: php, apache, wamp

**Short version:** PHP (or Apache??) is appending "C:" to the start of all relative URLs. How can I make it stop doing this?

**Detail:**
I'm trying to set up an AMP stack by hand on Windows Vista. This is just for internal use on my home network.

I've installed Apache 2.2, MySQL, and PHP 5.4. Everything's good except that PHP is appending "C:" to the beginning of every single URL. For example, even calling `php_info()` shows that php is adding "C:" to the start of `SCRIPT_PATH` and `PHP_SELF`. This is despite the fact that the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` variable is correct (C:\Apache2\htdocs):

From the PHP Variables section:

```
      Variable               Value
------------------------   ---------------
_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]     /test.php
_SERVER["SCRIPT_PATH"]     C:/test.php
_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]        C:/test.php
_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]   C:/Apache2/htdocs
```

Is there some setting I need to change in php.ini to correct this? It's totally screwing up links, such that I get lots of error messages like this in my Apache logs:

```
[error] [client 10.0.0.4] (20023)The given path was above the root path: Cannot map GET /C:/<rest of the actual path>
```

I've compared both php.ini and the Apache httpd.conf to the same files for an XAMPP installation on my laptop (which does not have this problem) and I cannot see any differences that seem like they would cause such a phenomenon.

This problem has ocurred with both Apache 2.4 + PHP 5.5 (both compiled with VC11) and with Apache 2.2 + PHP 5.4 (both compiled with VC9).

Comment: Those variables are supposed to contain local filenames, not URLs. Are your files on a different drive?

Comment: @Barmar No they are all on the same drive. And they are in "C:\Apache2\htdocs", not the root of C:

Comment: You can try `var_dump($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"])`, just to discard that it doesn't contain leading invisible chars.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this same problem and I fixed it by setting "FcgidFixPathinfo" to 0 in Apache's httpd.conf file.  Here's a link to where I found this.

http://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?p=18659

Answer (score 0):

There must be something subtley wrong with your config I would assume, what it is I cannot guess.

However if you are not interested in the challenge of installing an AMP stack manually and you just want something that does it all in one simple ready to go install, can I suggest you have a look at WAMPServer.

This installs Apache/MySQL and PHP in a one click install.

I suggest you make sure you have uninstalled all your other attempts at installing Apache and MySQL before you try WAMPServer as they will undoubtedly cause confusion.

Just a suggestion!

Comment: Yeah, I just went with XAMPP so I could proceed with hosting an ownCloud install on my internal home network. I'd still really like to know _what_ specifically is wrong with the Apache and/or PHP config.

Comment: @JoshuaHonig - You haven't posted the output of `var_dump($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"])` because it didn't show anything relevant?